# How to display the output of chars in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, select, formatting, char, sql-server-2016

When I run the following select:

```
SELECT 
    [Event] = CAST('Get the latest FULL backup' AS CHAR(108)),
    [backup_set_id]    = b.backup_set_id,
    [MediaSetID]       = b.media_set_id,
    backup_start_date  = b.backup_start_date,
    backup_finish_date = b.backup_finish_date,
    [Backup Type]      = b.type
FROM 
    msdb.dbo.backupset b
WHERE 
    backup_set_id = 238456

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    [Event] = CAST('Get the latest DIFFERENTIAL backup if any' AS CHAR(108)),
    [backup_set_id]    = b.backup_set_id,
    [MediaSetID]       = b.media_set_id,
    backup_start_date  = b.backup_start_date,
    backup_finish_date = b.backup_finish_date,
    [Backup Type]      = b.type
FROM 
    msdb.dbo.backupset b
WHERE 
    backup_set_id = 238474

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    [Event] = CAST('Get the LOG backup(s) if any' AS CHAR(108)),
    [backup_set_id]    = b.backup_set_id,
    [MediaSetID]       = b.media_set_id,
    backup_start_date  = b.backup_start_date,
    backup_finish_date = b.backup_finish_date,
    [Backup Type]      = b.type
FROM 
    msdb.dbo.backupset b
WHERE 
    backup_set_id = 239558
```

Everything is returned very nicely aligned, all the columns - especially the first one that I am mostly interested - take exactly the same amount of space and it is clear.

[image]

However, when I need to run those selects from inside a procedure, without using the `union all` as they are produced in different parts of the stored procedure - I still wanted to see all the columns formatted as before - taking the same amount of space, specially the first column.

that is not the case, as you can see on the picture below:

[image]

The question is - how can I make it - all these different selects be shown up displayed as before - specially the first column?

Comment: There are multiple dataset in that second image. In different datagrids. Each result set is completely separate. Why would you expect the presentation of one dataset to be effected by a completely different one? That would be like expecting `SELECT 1 AS One; SELECT REPLICATE('A',4000) AS one;` to have the `1` in a grid that is wide enough to fit 4,000 characters in, from a dataset that hasn't even been run yet.

Comment: Create a #temp table in your sproc and insert the results from your separate statements. Then query the temp table with a single query. You're returning 3+ different data sets from the procedure and it working exactly as expected.

Comment: no that is not possible as inside the procedure the code is way more complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [comment by Jacob H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7948962/jacob-h)

> Create a #temp table in your sproc and insert the results from your
>   separate statements. Then query the temp table with a single query.
>   You're returning 3+ different data sets from the procedure and it
>   working exactly as expected.

I created a temp table, and in different parts of my procedure, instead of selecting, I insert the data into the temp table.

At the end of my procedure, I then issue a select from the temp table.
This is shown in the code below.

```
                SET NOCOUNT ON
                IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#radhe_sp_getRestoreScripts') IS NOT NULL 
                        DROP TABLE #radhe_sp_getRestoreScripts

                CREATE TABLE #radhe_sp_getRestoreScripts( 
                [Event]               CHAR(108)                            NULL,
                [backup_set_id]       INT                                  NULL,
                [MediaSetID]          INT                                  NULL,
                [backup_start_date]   DATETIME                             NULL,
                [backup_finish_date]  DATETIME                             NULL,
                [Backup Type]         CHAR(1)                              NULL)


                INSERT INTO #radhe_sp_getRestoreScripts( 
                [Event]               ,
                [backup_set_id]       ,
                [MediaSetID]          ,
                [backup_start_date]   ,
                [backup_finish_date]  ,
                [Backup Type]         )
                SELECT 
                    [Event] = CAST('Get the latest FULL backup' AS CHAR(108)),
                    [backup_set_id]    = b.backup_set_id,
                    [MediaSetID]       = b.media_set_id,
                    backup_start_date  = b.backup_start_date,
                    backup_finish_date = b.backup_finish_date,
                    [Backup Type]      = b.type
                FROM 
                    msdb.dbo.backupset b
                WHERE 
                    backup_set_id = 238456



                INSERT INTO #radhe_sp_getRestoreScripts( 
                [Event]               ,
                [backup_set_id]       ,
                [MediaSetID]          ,
                [backup_start_date]   ,
                [backup_finish_date]  ,
                [Backup Type]         )
                SELECT 
                    [Event] = CAST('Get the latest DIFFERENTIAL backup if any' AS CHAR(108)),
                    [backup_set_id]    = b.backup_set_id,
                    [MediaSetID]       = b.media_set_id,
                    backup_start_date  = b.backup_start_date,
                    backup_finish_date = b.backup_finish_date,
                    [Backup Type]      = b.type
                FROM 
                    msdb.dbo.backupset b
                WHERE 
                    backup_set_id = 238474



                INSERT INTO #radhe_sp_getRestoreScripts( 
                [Event]               ,
                [backup_set_id]       ,
                [MediaSetID]          ,
                [backup_start_date]   ,
                [backup_finish_date]  ,
                [Backup Type]         )
                SELECT 
                    [Event] = CAST('Get the LOG backup(s) if any' AS CHAR(108)),
                    [backup_set_id]    = b.backup_set_id,
                    [MediaSetID]       = b.media_set_id,
                    backup_start_date  = b.backup_start_date,
                    backup_finish_date = b.backup_finish_date,
                    [Backup Type]      = b.type
                FROM 
                    msdb.dbo.backupset b
                WHERE 
                    backup_set_id = 239558


            SELECT
                [Event]               ,
                [backup_set_id]       ,
                [MediaSetID]          ,
                [backup_start_date]   ,
                [backup_finish_date]  ,
                [Backup Type] 
            FROM #radhe_sp_getRestoreScripts
```

and this is the result set (very nicely displayed):

[image]